# how to monitor operation on mac platform

Tags: macos, kernel-extension, file-monitoring

I am trying to get file open/write/create operation, I have tried fslogger which can only get file creation/delete....and other operations, can not get open/close operation, 
then I wrote a driver to do it, I can get open/close operation but can not get create operation, what's more,  it's too messy!
for example, if I open a file and modify it, and then close it, the driver gets a lot of open/write operations..I have no way to tell which one is really caused by user open/close operation..
any hints about this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be the KAuth system. You install your kauth handler (as a kernel extension) and get various callback codes when someone tries to create, open or close a file. This involves getting your callback in the critical path of opening files, so whatever you do has to be quick!

To quote:

> KAUTH_SCOPE_FILEOP defines the following actions.
>
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_OPEN
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_CLOSE
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_CLOSE_MODIFIED
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_RENAME
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_EXCHANGE
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_LINK
> - KAUTH_FILEOP_EXEC
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html

If you're writing a kext you then have the question of how to get that info back into userland. FWIW I used Kqueue but you may have success with another method (let me know in the comments if you do!).

More info on [Kauth here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2127/_index.html) and [KQueue here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html). It's not brilliantly documented, but there's enough info between those two to work out what you need to do.

Comment: hi Joe, thanks your reply, and actually I am using kauth. but I met an issue mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564984/how-come-osx-kernel-get-so-many-times-of-file-operations)

Comment: It's been a while since I did this, but I thought I got enough information. I can't remember much more than this, sorry.

Comment: it's ok, I feel it's no way to get what i want just according to the kauth...it seems there are too many stories behind a simple open/close in userspace on Mac platform. whatever, thanks